# Nothing happens when I close my laptop lid or press the power button (Kubuntu 14.04.3, Thinkpad X250)

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, laptop, power-management, acpi

I'm on Kubuntu 14.04.3 on a ThinkPad X250.

I tried to configure what happens when I close my laptop lid or when I press my power button in the "Configure Energy Saving" dialog in the "System Settings". But no matter what I choose (Sleep, Turn Off screen, Lock Screen, Shutdown) nothing happens if I press the power button or close the laptop lid. It used to work on my ThinkPad X230.

I have a couple of "activities" that had custom settings for energy saving, but now I set them all to "Don't use special settings".

I'm aware of [Power button in Lubuntu 13.10 will not suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363510/power-button-in-lubuntu-13-10-will-not-suspend). I tried the solution but it did not work for me.

When I perform Sleep, Restart, Shut down, etc.from the launcher menu everything works fine. I can also perform these actions from the terminal using the `shutdown` command and I can suspend the machine using 'pm-suspend'.

Following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205815/138101) to a related question I added

```
logger in /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh, presumably "Power button pressed"
```

to `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`. Now, if I do `sudo /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` an entry in `/var/log/syslog` is made. However, if I press the power button no entry is made, so I guess this script is not executed when I press the power button.

Following [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/683654/458355) I made a script that prints out the value of

```
/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state
```

every second. Opposing to what was reported there the LID state is correctly detected.

I ran 'acpi_listen'. I get a message when closing and opening the lid:

```
button/lid LID close
button/lid LID open
```

However, I do not get a message when pressing the power button. So does that mean that the "closing the lid" and the "power button" problem are unrelated? I realized that in '/etc/acpi/' and '/etc/acpi/events' there seem to be no files handling lid close:

```
$ ls /etc/acpi/events/
asus-keyboard-backlight-down  asus-wireless-off  ibm-wireless   powerbtn       tosh-wireless
asus-keyboard-backlight-up    asus-wireless-on   lenovo-undock  thinkpad-cmos

$ ls /etc/acpi/
asus-keyboard-backlight.sh  asus-wireless.sh  events  ibm-wireless.sh  powerbtn.sh  tosh-wireless.sh  undock.sh
```

I also run Windows on the same machine and there the power button and closing the lid works normally, so it cannot be a mechanical defect.

Any ideas how I can make my Laptop go to sleep when I press the power button or close the laptop lid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power button in Lubuntu 13.10 will not suspend](http://askubuntu.com/questions/363510/power-button-in-lubuntu-13-10-will-not-suspend)

Comment: @Daniel 2 Completely different issues.

Comment: @Fabian Rost please Edit your question with the result of `sudo shutdown now` in your terminal. I do realize that this isn't sleep.

Comment: @Daniel, I tried the proposed solution  from Power button in Lubuntu 13.10 will not suspend and as David Cole just pointed out it doesn't work.

Comment: OK.  Have you tried `sudo shutdown now` like David suggested?

Comment: `sudo shutdown now` turns of my screen and makes my computer not to respond anymore. However, it will not completely shutdown (power light and cpu fan remain on).

Comment: I forgot to mention that everything works fine if I use the launcher menu. Furthermore `sudo reboot` reboots my machine and `sudo shutdown -P now` shuts my system down.

Comment: My apologies. I am used to clean Ubuntu. Kubuntu may require a -P or maybe sometimes a -Pf to power off with `shutdown` @FabianRost

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/631895/458355

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/660874/458355 and http://askubuntu.com/q/639952/458355

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/395428/458355

Comment: Maybe related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/863834#30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Kubuntu 15.10. Now, closing the laptop lid is correctly handled (the action I select in the System Settings of KDE is performed).

However, the power button is not yet functional.