# Nothing happens when I close the lid or press power button

Tags: laptop, power-management, hibernate, acpi

I just installed on Ubuntu 14.04.3 on my laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad X230). Everything works fine except:

- closing the lid
- pressing power button

while the computer is on does nothing, even though I have the settings (under System Settings => Power) that both should trigger hibernation. (Hibernation works fine when I pick it from the menu; also, nothing happens if I set the power button/close lid actions to suspend/shutdown, either.)

Using a script that prints out the value of

> /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state

every second and then closing and reopening the lid shows that the event is not detected at all. I have kernel 3.16.0-38-generic installed.

How can I fix this?